# Randomly get: "TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm drawing several charts on one of my webpage, however I randomly get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor
```

I've tried to narrow down the issue by displaying one chart only but I still get the error message and no charts are drawn, about 50% of the time. When I don't get the errors the chart(s) is drawn properly.

I've read multiple forums and [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts) but I can't see what is wrong. I have basically the same code as the mentioned documentation, except that my functions are declared BEFORE the `setOnLoadCallback`, otherwise they get `undefined`.

Some of my (simplified) code:

MyPage.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    // loading CSS
   </head>
     <body>
        <p>My page content...</p>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
           <script src="/js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           // loading more scripts (moment.js, query.countdown.js, bootstrap.js...)
    </body>
</html>
```

In home.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.href == 'XXXXXController') {  

    // This chart draws a dual axis chart showing revenues and expenses
    function drawRevenuesExpenses() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/draw_dual_lineChart",
            data: "someParameters",
            dataType:"json"
            }).done(function (jsonData) {          
                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
                // Set chart's options
                var options = jsonData[1]['options'];
                // Instantiate and draw the chart
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('dual_chart_revenues_expenses')); 
                chart.draw(data_chart, options);
            });
    }

    // This chart draws the resort's affluence (number of tourists per day)
    function drawAffluence() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/draw_single_lineChart",
            data: "someParameters",
            dataType:"json"
            }).done(function (jsonData) {          
                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
                // Set chart's options
                var options = jsonData[1]['options'];
                // Instantiate and draw the chart
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('single_chart_affluence')); 
                chart.draw(data_chart, options);
            });
    }

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRevenuesExpenses);
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAffluence);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the documentation is pretty stale at this point...

don't recommend using more than one `setOnLoadCallback` statement

actually, you can place the `callback` directly in the `load` statement

and you can depend on the `callback` to know when the page is ready

no need for --> `$(document).ready`

try following setup, load google before anything else...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawCharts() {
  if (window.location.href == 'XXXXXController') {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/draw_dual_lineChart",
          data: "someParameters",
          dataType:"json"
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
          // Set chart's options
          var options = jsonData[1]['options'];
          // Instantiate and draw the chart
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('dual_chart_revenues_expenses'));
          chart.draw(data_chart, options);
      });

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/draw_single_lineChart",
          data: "someParameters",
          dataType:"json"
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
          // Set chart's options
          var options = jsonData[1]['options'];
          // Instantiate and draw the chart
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('single_chart_affluence'));
          chart.draw(data_chart, options);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I restructured my code as you said: moved it outside the `$(document).ready`, removed all `setOnLoadCallback ` and loaded `drawCharts` directly in the `load` statement, however I still get the same problem. Two things to mention: I need to put the `load` statement after the `drawCharts` function or it gets undefined; and a simple F5 always triggers the errors. When I refresh the cache (CTRL+R in Firefox) the charts are properly displayed.. I suspect something wrong with loading the files/modules...

Comment: That's already at the bottom of the page, with some other `<script>`. I guess it doesn't matter if I load some other files in between? Or do the Google ones have to be the really last loaded? I edited my question with the page layout.

Comment: Weird... Now I can only reproduce the issue if Firefox' Firebug console is opened... It works fine when Firebug is close or in another browser (Chrome, IE11). Thanks for the help anyway, my code looks cleaner now.

Comment: If you reference a function in one script but it is not defined until a later script, it won't be defined yet.

Answer (score 3):

WhiteHat is right about everything, except you need to load the table-chart before using it. Like this:

```
    google.charts.load("current", {
        packages : [ "corechart","table" ]
    });
```